# ManyToMany self-referencing relation - how to optimize this code?

Tags: php, optimization, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

how can I optimize this code. the only way I've found to update related documents was to remove all old relations and set new one. this makes many useless delete/insert queries for relation that hasn't changed

**Controller Action:**

```
    foreach ($entity->getRelatedDocuments() as $document) {
        $oldRDs[] = $document;
    }
    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        // filter $originalTags to contain tags no longer present
        $newRDs = $entity->getRelatedDocuments();

        // assign old and new relations
        if (!isset($oldRDs)) {
            $addRDs = $newRDs;
        } else {
            $delRDs = $oldRDs;
            $addRDs = $newRDs;
        } 
        // if there are old one remove them
        if (isset($delRDs)) {
            foreach ($delRDs as $document) {
                $document->removeDocument($entity);
            }
        }
        // if there are new one store them
        if (isset($addRDs)) {
            foreach ($addRDs as $document) {
                $document->addDocument($entity);
            }
        }       

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('document_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }
```

**Entity Class:**

```
/**
 * @var string $relatedDocuments
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Document")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="nb_link_documents_documents",
 *               joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document1_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *               inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document2_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
private $relatedDocuments;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->relatedDocuments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addDocument(\NF\FundBundle\Entity\Document $relatedDocuments)
{
    $this->relatedDocuments[] = $relatedDocuments;
}

public function removeDocument(\NF\FundBundle\Entity\Document $relatedDocuments)
{
    foreach ($this->relatedDocuments as $key => $document) {
        if ($document->getId() == $relatedDocuments->getId())
            unset ($this->relatedDocuments[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just check if any of the related documents is in both `$delRDs` and `$addRDs` and if so, remove them from those both variables or skip it while your deleting and adding them?

Comment: unfortunatelly this won't work. I've added after line "$addRDs = $newRDs;" this >>>
    foreach ($delRDs as $dKey => $dDoc) {
        foreach ( $addRDs as $aKey => $aDoc) {
                        if ($aDoc->getId() == $dDoc->getId()) {
                            unset($addRDs[$aKey]);
                            unset($delRDs[$dKey]);
                        }
                    }
                }
and then added 2 relations, result: id pairs 1,3 1,4 3,1 4,1 then removed one relation, result: id pairs 3,1 all other were removed. this case I've tried to work out on many ways but none worked.